# Function is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I am pushing this calculation a little further and editing it. Perhaps someone could help.

The function $s(t)$ defined as
$$
s(t) = -\alpha r_i -\alpha r_0 \left( \frac{\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i-1}{\frac{e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}}}{\sum \limits_{h=j}^i{\frac{e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}}} \right)
$$
with
$$
\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}=\prod \limits_{l=j, l\neq h}^i \left(\gamma^h-\gamma^l \right), r_i = r_0 \gamma^i
$$
where $\gamma > 0, N_0 > 0, r_0 > 0 $.
It can be easily plotted and seen that this function is always decreasing. However, I want to show this analytically. My attempt is as under, but I am stuck on how to proceed further. Any other method is also appreciated.

$$
s'(t) = \frac{\alpha^2 r_0}{N_0} \left(\frac{\sum \limits_{h=j}^i{\frac{e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}} \times \sum \limits_{h=j}^{i-1}{\gamma^h \frac{ e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}} - \sum \limits_{h=j}^{i-1}{\frac{e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}} \times \sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{\gamma^h \frac{e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}}}{\left( \sum \limits_{h=j}^i{\frac{e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}} \right)^2} \right)
$$

If $s(t)$ is always decreasing, then $ s'(t) < 0, \forall t $, and we must have

$$
\sum \limits_{h=j}^i{\frac{e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}} \times \sum \limits_{h=j}^{i-1}{\gamma^h \frac{ e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}} - \sum \limits_{h=j}^{i-1}{\frac{e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}} \times \sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{\gamma^h \frac{e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}} < 0
$$

or

$$
\frac{\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i-1}{\gamma^h \frac{e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}}}{\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i-1}{\frac{ e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}}}
 < \frac{\sum \limits_{h=j}^i{\gamma^h\frac{e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}}} {\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}}}
$$

Obviously, $\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}$ has one factor more than $\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}$, and therefore, due to the involvement of the summation index $h$, these can't be compared. However, taking their absolute values, one can compare them easily. Thus

$$
\lvert{\frac{1}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}} < \lvert{\frac{1}{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}}\rvert \; \; \;
{\&} \; \; \;
\lvert{\frac{\gamma^h}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}}\rvert < \lvert{\frac{\gamma^h}{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}}\rvert, \;\; \text{as $\gamma > 1$ }
$$

Now

$$
   \lvert{\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{\gamma^h  e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}}}\rvert
    \le
    \sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{\gamma^h  e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\lvert{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}\rvert}}
   \le
\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{\gamma^h  e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\lvert{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}\rvert}}
$$

$$
\implies
\lvert{\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{\gamma^h  e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}}}\rvert
    \le
    \sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{\gamma^h  e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\lvert{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}\rvert}}
$$

Further, by dropping the $i^{th}$ term from the summation, we have

$$
\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i-1}{ \frac{\gamma^h  e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\lvert{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}\rvert}}
    <
    \sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{\gamma^h  e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\lvert{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}\rvert}}
$$

also,

$$
\lvert{\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i-1}{ \frac{\gamma^h  e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}}}\rvert
    \le
    \sum \limits_{h=j}^{i-1}{ \frac{\gamma^h  e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\lvert{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}\rvert}}
$$

Since $\gamma > 1$, therefore, $$\gamma^h > 0 \quad \text{for any} \quad h \in \mathbb{Z}^+$$. Thus from above, we can write

$$
 \lvert{\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{ e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}}}\rvert
    <
    \sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{ e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\lvert{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}}\rvert}.
$$

Now combining the above

$$
    \frac{\lvert{\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{\gamma^h  e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}}}\rvert}
    {\lvert{\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{ e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}}}\rvert}
    >
    \frac{\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{\gamma^h  e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\lvert{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}\rvert}}}
    {\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{ e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\lvert{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}\rvert}}}
    \ge
    \frac{\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i-1}{ \frac{\gamma^h  e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\lvert{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}\rvert}}}
    {\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{ e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\lvert{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}\rvert}}}
$$

By the $\triangle$ular inequality on the right numerator, we can wirte

$$
    \frac{\lvert{\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{\gamma^h  e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}}}\rvert}
    {\lvert{\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{ e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{hi}^{\left(j\right)}}\rvert}}}
    >
    \frac{\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{\gamma^h  e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\lvert{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}}}\rvert}
    {\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{ e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\lvert{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}\rvert}}}
    \ge
    \frac{\lvert{\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i-1}{ \frac{\gamma^h  e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}}}\rvert}
    {\sum \limits_{h=j}^{i}{ \frac{ e^{-\alpha\frac{\gamma^h}{N_0} t}}{\lvert{\Gamma_{h,i-1}^{\left(j\right)}}\rvert}}}
$$

Now how to proceed further?

Comment: Why do you care about this function?

Comment: I am doing some analysis where this needs to be shown as a decreasing function since further analysis is based on this.